# Sub Activities under TabActivity and Back button in android

Tags: android, back, android-tabactivity, subactivity

I have to show multiple activities under same tab. I have followed the below
http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/08/multiple-android-activities-in.html. But when I'am in sub activity and press back button, it is restarting the main/tab1 activity again. In my case, I have to download some data from web and display in a listview in Main/Tab1 activity and start the sub activity on click of list item under the same tab. Now If I press back, again its downloading data from web. What should I do to show the main activity without restarting it? Please help me.

Comment: pressing back IMO will never restart your activities in the tab. Are you doing anything in onResume or onStart of Main/Tab1?

Comment: No, iam not overriding onstart or onresume. Iam downloading from web in oncrate only. But its again recreating the activity if i press back.

Comment: Finally got it. 
https://github.com/snowpong/stacksintabs
This is what exactly I was looking for.. Thanks waichun.